# Stuck with Drush on OS X with AMPPS and Homebrew

Tags: 7, drush

I am setting up a new development environment on a local machine and am using AMPPS. I have installed Drush using Homebrew and am running a Mac (OS X 10.12.5 Sierra).

I have successfully installed a fresh Drupal site in my development environment. When I attempt to run a drush command, I get the Drush status along with the classic bootstrap/jailed shell message:

```
Command pm-list needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal[error]
environment to run this command.
The drush command 'pm-list' could not be executed.                                                                 [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                       [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select
another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command
line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a
jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
```

Here is the output of `drush status`:

```
Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version         :  7.54                                             
 Site URI               :  http://default                                   
 Database driver        :  mysql                                            
 Database hostname      :  localhost                                        
 Database port          :                                                   
 Database username      :  myuser                                            
 Database name          :  drupal                                           
 PHP executable         :  /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin/php              
 PHP configuration      :  /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/etc/php.ini          
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                           
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.15/libexec/drush.php 
 Drush version          :  8.1.15                                           
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                             
 Drush configuration    :                                                   
 Drush alias files      :                                                   
 Drupal root            :  /Applications/AMPPS/www/drupal/docroot       
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php                       
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

Please note:

- I have tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in `sites/default/settings.php` and restarting the server
- I added the path to drush to php via `export DRUSH_PHP=/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin/php`
- I am executing the command within the docroot of the drupal installation
- I do not have a `~/.my.cnf` file
- symlink in `/usr/local/bin` for PHP goes to Homebrew's instead of AMPPS's but it's for version 7.1.10 and I'm using PHP 5.6

There are a lot of posts on this with slightly different details or environments and I'm having no luck deriving a solution from those so I thought I would post my issue with the specific scenario.

I mostly used these instructions:
https://www.drupal.org/node/954766

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I did export the Drush PHP path, I had not added the link to AMPPS' mysql bin in .bash_profile. That solved my issue.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify the path to Drush

I had

export PHP_ID="php-5.6"

export PATH="/Applications/AMPPS/$PHP_ID/bin:/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin:/Users//.composer/vendor/bin/drush:$PATH"

there is good info here [Stuck with Drush on OS X with AMPPS and Homebrew](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248510/stuck-with-drush-on-os-x-with-ampps-and-homebrew)

Comment: Just an FYI, your answer is basically what I said and the link you provided goes to this page.